# showing sphere like object is a $C^{\infty}$ surface.

Tags: geometry, multivariable-calculus, surfaces

For $a,b,c >0$ let,

$E(a,b,c) = \{ (x,y,z) \in \mathbb {R^3} : \frac {x^2}{a^2} +\frac {y^2}{b^2} + \frac {z^2}{c^2} =1 \}$

How do i show that E(a,b,c) is a $C^{\infty}$ surface in $\mathbb {R^3}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $f_{a,b,c}(x,y,z)={x^2\over a^2}+{y^2\over b^2}+{z^2\over c^2}$.

$f_{a,b,c}$ is a submersion on $R^3-\{0\}$ and $E(a,b,c)=f^{-1}_{a,b,c}(1)\subset R^3-\{0\}$.

Comment: so what i think your saying is that $f^{-1}$ is infinitely differentiable?

Comment: yes, it is a $C^{\infty}$-manifold since $f_{a,b,c}$ is $C^{\infty}$ this a standard way to show that a subset of $R^n$ is a $C^{\infty}$ manifold.